# Jquery Conditional Statements for Multiple Checkbox Values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to posting/stackoverflow, so please forgive me for any faux pas. I have multiple buttons and checkboxes that I need to store the values of to place into conditional statements.

The HTML code:

```
<h1>SECTION 1: GENDER</h1>
    <p>What is your gender?</p>
    <input type="button" onclick="storeGender(this.value)" value="Male"/>
    <input type="button" onclick="storeGender(this.value)" value="Female"/>

    <hr />

    <h1>SECTION 2: AGE</h1>
    <p>What is your age?</p>
    <input type="button" onclick="storeAge(this.value)" value="18–22"/>
    <input type="button" onclick="storeAge(this.value)" value="23–30"/>

    <hr />

    <h1>SECTION 3: TRAITS</h1>
    <h3>Choose Two:</h3>
    <form>
        <input name="field" type="checkbox" value="1"/> Casual <br />
        <input name="field" type="checkbox" value="10"/> Cheerful <br />
        <input name="field" type="checkbox" value="100"/> Confident  <br />
        <input name="field" type="checkbox" value="1000"/> Tough  <br />
        <input type="button" id="storeTraits" value="SUBMIT" /> <br />
    </form>

    <hr />

    <h2>Here is what I suggest</h2>
    <p id="feedback">Feedback goes here.</p>
```

jQuery code:

```
 // set up variables
var gender;
var age;
var string;

$(document).ready(function() {
    startGame();
    $("#storeTraits").click( function() {
        serializeCheckbox();
    }
    ); }
);

function startGame() {
    document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = "Answer all the questions.";
}

function storeGender(value) {
    gender = value;
}

function storeAge(value) {
    age = value;
}

function serializeCheckbox() {
    // clear out any previous selections
    string = [ ];
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

    for( var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++ ) {
        if(inputs[i].type == "checkbox" && inputs[i].name == "field") {
            if(inputs[i].checked == true) {
                string.push(inputs[i].value);
            }
        }
    }
    checkFeedback();
}

//Limit number of checkbox selections
$(function(){
    var max = 2;
    var checkboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');

    checkboxes.change(function(){
        var current = checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;
        checkboxes.filter(':not(:checked)').prop('disabled', current >= max);
    });
});

function checkFeedback() {
    if(gender == "Male") {
        if (age == "18–22" && string == 11){
            document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = "test1";
        } else if (age == "18–22" && string == 110){
            document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = "test2";
        } else if (age == "18–22" && string == 1100){
            document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = "test3";
        } else if (age == "18–22" && string == 101){
            document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = "test4";
        } 
    }
}
```

I found this code on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GNDAG/ which is what I want to do for adding together my trait values. However, when I try to incorporate it my conditional statements don't work. How do I add the code from the jsfiddle example and get the conditional statements to work? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an integer, not a string array. Here's the code you need:

```
var traits = 0;

$('input[name=field]:checked').each(function () {
    traits += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
});
```

This will set the "traits" variable to an integer like 1, 11, 101, or 1001.

BTW: The second parameter to `parseInt()` is the base.

But a few suggestions:

1. Don't use "string" as a variable name.
2. Use radio buttons for gender and age.
3. Put all the input elements in the form.
4. Have one button that submits the form.
5. Attach a handler to the form submit event, and do your processing in that function, but call `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the form from submitting to the server. Alternatively, you could have the single button not be a submit button and attach an on-click handler to it.

Here's a [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/john_s/sMR7d/) with the code above and all the suggestions implemented.

Comment: Sorry, I should've played around with it more thoroughly.

`if(gender == 'Male') {
   if (age == '18–22' && traits == 101){
   return 'test1';
   } else if (age == '23–30' && traits == 101){
   return 'test2';
   }
  }`

Doesn't work for me. How do I get the correct return string?

Comment: @user2230743 - Sorry about that. I fixed the [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/john_s/sMR7d/1/). I forgot to add ":checked" to the selectors when getting the radio button values.